# Copy multiple files to multiple destinations

Tags: bash, ssh

When copying over SSH from one UNIX system to another, is it possible to copy each file to  different destinations in one operation (ie. avoid overhead of setting up a new SSH connection for each file), for example by specifying the sources and targets in a file something like this:

```
/Users/apple/a --> /home/orange/.
/etc/var/b --> /usr/local/var/.
/other/c --> /wildly/different/.
```

Comment: I'm disappointed that this was closed outright. For the record, I voted to move it to Super User.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy you could take would be to construct a "root" directory on your local system (the sender) mimicking the file structure you would like to have on the receiving machine, and then just copy that to root (`/`) on the other machine. For example, you might construct the following temp directory as a "root":

```
/tmp/root
/tmp/root/home/orange/a
/tmp/root/usr/local/var/b
/tmp/root/wildly/different/c
```

And then just copy `/tmp/root` to `/` on the remote machine, which would just be a single copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could write something like this:

```
mkdir ./tmp/
ln -s /Users/apple/a /etc/var/b /other/c ./tmp/
# Now ./tmp/ has symbolic links to all these files.
# Tar the files to STDOUT, and pipe that over SSH to a
# tar that's reading from STDIN:
tar -ch tmp/* \
  | ssh USER@HOST ' tar -xf -
                    mv tmp/a /home/orange/
                    mv tmp/b /usr/local/var/
                    mv tmp/c /wildly/different/
                    rmdir tmp/
                  '
rm -r tmp/
```

. . . not very elegant, but it only requires a single SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [SSH session sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949316/can-i-use-an-existing-ssh-connection-and-execute-scp-over-that-tunnel-without-re/15949814). No more reauthenticating, so it's fast.